# KVM Guest installation

Tags: kvm

After ran below command

```
virt-install --name=vm01 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm01.img,size=10 --ram=512 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel6 --network bridge:br0 --nographics --cdrom=/home/ISO/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso
```

I am facing below error

```
SeaBIOS (version seabios-0.6.1.2-26.el6)

gPXE (http://etherboot.org) - 00:03.0 C100 PCI2.10 PnP BBS PMM1FE0@10 C100

Booting from DVD/CD...
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code...
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
Loading bootlogo...

Initializing gfx code...
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
```

During Guest KVM installation I am facing above error
but

```
[root@ramlo images]# virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     vm01                           running

unable to install Guest KVM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these methods instead.

Won't automatically open a install window, you can connect afterwards.

```
$ sudo virt-install -n vm01 -r 256 \
    --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm01.img,bus=virtio,size=10 -c \
    /home/ISO/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso --accelerate --network \
    network=bridge:br0 --connect=qemu:///system --vnc --noautoconsole -v
```

Will automatically pop a GUI up where you can interact with the installation.

```
$ virt-install -n vm01 -r 256 \
    --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm01.img,bus=virtio,size=10 -c \
    /home/ISO/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso --accelerate --network \
    network=bridge:br0 --connect=qemu:///system --vnc -v
```

The difference being the `--noautoconsole`. You also might be running into an issue with using `/home/ISO`. I'm using Fedora and on that system there's a piece of software called SELinux which blocks KVM/QEMU from using `/home/ISO`, so I typically keep the `.iso` files under `/var/lib/libvirt/images`.

On Ubuntu App Armor is the equivalent to SELinux, and so it might be blocking you from using `/home/ISO`.

When I attempt to use a directory that SELinux isn't OK with I get this type of error:

```
Starting install...
Allocating 'vm01.img'                                  |  10 GB  00:00:00
```

> ERROR    internal error process exited while connecting to monitor: char device redirected to /dev/pts/7 (label charserial0)
>       qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/saml/projects/machines/ISOs/debian-live-7.4-amd64-lxde-desktop.iso,if=none,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw: could not open disk image /home/saml/projects/machines/ISOs/debian-live-7.4-amd64-lxde-desktop.iso: Permission denied

#### References

- [Ubuntu 12.04 » Ubuntu Server Guide » Virtualization » libvirt](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/libvirt.html)
- [KVM: Connect to a virtual machine(SSH, VNC, Console, virt-viewer etc)](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/02/kvm-connect-to-a-virtual-machinessh-vnc-console-virt-viewer-etc.html)

Comment: Is it recommended to store .iso on `/var/lib/libvirt/images`? Previously I encountered the same permission denied problem on RHEL (SELinux Enable) and mitigate it by storing iso file in /tmp for testing purpose. On [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html) fedora example, the iso can be put in /home/user/. But I cannot make it work on my setup. Any advices?

Comment: @IvanChau - no I don't think so, but that directory is open to KVM accessing it. `/tmp` would probably fine as well. If you're looking for a more permanent location then I'd spend the time setting up App Armor/SELinux to allow KVM access to some other location.

Comment: Under /root, `drwxr-xr-x. qemu qemu system_u:object_r:virt_image_t:s0 vmiso` for ISO directory and `-rw-r--r--. qemu qemu system_u:object_r:virt_content_t:s0 dvd.iso` for ISO file still leads to permission denied issue. Could the .img and .iso stored in *different* directory?

Comment: SELinux: change security context for non-default image directories: `semanage fcontext --add -t virt_image_t '/home/foobar(/.*)?'`. Check and confirm: `semanage fcontext -l | grep virt_image_t`. Restore (change effectively) context to virt_image_t: `restorecon -R -v /home/foobar`. Confirm: `ls -aZ /home/foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

please use below method

```
virt-install -n vmname -r 2048 --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntulucid \
    --disk /kvm/images/disk/vmname_boot.img,device=disk,bus=ide,size=40,sparse=true,format=raw \
    -w bridge=br0,model=e1000 --vnc --noautoconsole \
    -c /home/ISO/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.iso
```